# update Laravel 5.6 to 5.7 verification email work on resend via middleware but not on new registration

Tags: laravel

I have update my existing project from laravel 5.6 to 5.7 for using email verification system but email not sent on register
how ever by using this middleware in route
->middleware('verified');
when i resend email. It works perfect

Comment: Check this https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/27 and debug the email using log file. Whether you are getting output

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the `SendEmailVerificationNotification` event and listener must be added when upgrading to `5.7`.

Adding this to [App\Providers\EventServiceProvider](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php) solved it for me.

```
protected $listen = [
    // ...
    \Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered::class => [
        \Illuminate\Auth\Listeners\SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
    ],
];
```

Also added a PR to include this in the `5.7` upgrade section [in the docs](https://github.com/laravel/docs/pull/4495/).